# Cannot access Yii2 vendor classes

Tags: php, yii, centos, yii2, centos6

I have a fresh install of Yii2 on CentOS 6.

I have all `php-` packages necessary: `cli`, `mcrypt`, `common`, `gd`, `mbstring`, `pgsql`, `pdo`, and `mysql`.

The site is also setup as a virtual host on `httpd`. The only weird thing I did in this section is to `AllowOverride All` because I wanted my htaccess files in the advanced application to take effect.

When I access the site, it shows up on the browser. However, when I try to do a `yii migrate` or if I access a page which uses any yii class in the vendor folder, PHP thros a fatal error saying the file is not found. But the actual files are on the server.

How do I rectify this?

p.s: I ran the `requirements.php` file and it says DB classes are not found; claiming it cannot find the PDO class. But I have these installed, as earlier stated.

Comment: remember running requirements.php on the command line runs PHP in CLI mode, so it might well report modules not in the build that are actually in the apache build. Also, check your PATH is right for the PHP version you have installed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the PHP version in my CLI was an experimental build of 5.5, installed from the `remi` repo

I removed this using `yum remove php55-php-*`
The wildcard is because I am lazy, and cannot remember which packages from PHP 5.5 I had installed.

I also removed this installation of PHP from my `$PATH` variable, and...

### It works!